# put gridview on a updatepanel

Tags: asp.net, gridview, updatepanel

First I'm a beginner at ASP.NET. I know a lot of classic ASP.

I'm working on a application/framework oracle utilities. In the past I have created 'clips' in classic ASP, which are gridviews. There several clips positioned on a web page. All these gridviews do have page indexing. At this moment there 5 records per grid shown. So if there ar 18 records then there are 4 pages.

The paging, data binding etc. is working fine.

BUT what I already said there are several clips on a page. And for instance the user want to look at a clip at the middle of the page. When he click on the next page for that clip a submit is executed and the whole page is submitted and positioned at the top of the page. That is not user friendly because the user have to search/scroll down to the clip where he was looking at.

Were I'm looking for, I don't know if I say it correctly, to bind every gridview of a clip to his own update panel, so that if the user clicks on the next page of a certain gridview, only that gridview is refreshed and not the complete page (AJAX?).

Here is the code:

```
namespace Lodestar.Web.WebParts {
    public class CustomerCustomWebpartGasGVExSub : WebPart {
        //define variables

        private GridView CustConGrid;
        //I have defined this by myself
        private UpdatePanel UpdatePanel1;

        private LiteralControl LinkBox;

        public override string Title {
            get {
                return _title;
            }
            set {
                _title = value;
            }
        }

        //construtor
        public CustomerCustomWebpartGasGVExSub() {}

        protected override void CreateChildControls() {
            Controls.Clear();

            //Create the contract view.
            CustConGrid = new GridView();
            CustConGrid.EnableTheming = true;
        CustConGrid.SkinID = "CompacGrid";
        CustConGrid.PageSize = 5;
        CustConGrid.AllowPaging = true;
        CustConGrid.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        CustConGrid.EmptyDataText = I18n.FM("GVClip_NoContracts");

        //I have defined this by myself    
        UpdatePanel1 = new UpdatePanel(); 

        //Create the db instance and retrieve the Customer UID and ID from the session page.
        ....
        using (DataTable dt = db.GetEntity("CUSTOMER", filter)) {
            //Retrieve the Customer information from the database.
            ....                
            //Render the contract table panel.

            using (DataTable cdt = TableFromReader(cdb.GetDataReader(xslFileGasGV, "StoredProcedure", lsdbparams, 9999, 1))) {

            }

            //Contract ID
            HyperLinkField ContractIdFld = new HyperLinkField();
            ContractIdFld.HeaderText = I18n.FM("ContractID");
            ContractIdFld.DataTextField = "CONTRACTID";
            ContractIdFld.DataNavigateUrlFields = new string[] {"UIDC"};
            string url = string.Format("~/..../..../......asp?SessionId={0}", HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlEncode(SessionContext.Id));
            ContractIdFld.DataNavigateUrlFormatString = url + "&UIDC={0}";
            CustConGrid.Columns.Add(ContractIdFld);

            //Revision
            BoundField RevisionFld = new BoundField();
            RevisionFld.HeaderText = I18n.FM("GRevision");
            RevisionFld.DataField = "REVISION";
            CustConGrid.Columns.Add(RevisionFld);

            //Contract Type Code

            //Category

            //Status

            //Bind and add row
            CustConGrid.PageIndexChanging += new GridViewPageEventHandler(CustConGrid_PageIndexChanging);
            Controls.Add(CustConGrid);
            CustConGrid.DataBind();
        //UpdatePanel1.PageIndexChanging += new    GridViewPageEventHandler(CustConGrid_PageIndexChanging);
//Tried something by myself, but is not working
UpdatePanel1.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(CustConGrid);
            }
        }

        protected override void RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter writer) {}

        public DataTable TableFromReader(IDataReader dr) {}

        void CustConGrid_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
        {
            CustConGrid.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
            CustConGrid.DataBind();
        }

        private void GetSessionInfo() {}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve a problem of maintaining scroll position after postback by adding this MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback in page tag.

```
<%@ Page Title="" MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true"  Language="C#"
```

Comment: When I google on 'MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback' then I found also some threads that is possible to put this in the Page_Load like this: `code`    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.LoadPage.MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack = True

End Sub But this seems to is more vb.net in stead of c# or not? And I read also that it is possible to add this to the web.config: <pages maintainScrollPositionOnPostBack="true">. Next week I will try this.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have just test it and it is working for us. I have added:
    MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true"

to the page tag in the web.config.

BUT to learn a little bit more of ASP.NET is it also possible with a updatepanel in the code behind? (for example in the method page_onload{})